# How do I install two versions of WordPress on 1 server?

Tags: installation

I am installing on a local machine using `localhost`. I have a "learning" version of WordPress @ `http://localhost/wordpress` and I want to create another version of WordPress (@ `http://localhost/jiewmeng`) I want to test and maybe move to a real server later. I found that when I extracted a fresh copy of WordPress into `localhost/jiewmeng`, it probably detects the WordPress database and uses that? All the data I get is from the "learning" version of WordPress.

How do i set this up so that the 2 installations of WordPress are separate?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The database connection constants are defined in the wp-config.php file. Whether the 2 wp-config.php files in the jiewmeng directory and the WordPress directory are the same?

You need to create 2 different databases and set their constants in the respective wp-config.php files.

Comment: i actually just extracted a fresh wordpress for the `localhost/jiewmeng` version. it didnt even have a `wp-config.php` i tried to add 1 and change the database name, it still connects to the old `localhost/wordpress` install. i even tried renaming the database from `wordpress` to `wordpress_old` and try again, both installs fail as they tried to connect to the same database. the workaround i had was create a new vhost `http://jiewmeng` to host my 2nd wordpress and it works. curious to know why this happens tho

Comment: I'd be curious to know what kind of a setup you're running on your local machine.  What you're running into is a server configuration/administration issue ... not a WordPress issue.  You can have two separate WordPress installations on the same server connect to different databases *because you explicitly identify the database* when you set up WordPress.  If they're both pointing to the same DB, it's because either you told them to, or your server did ... WP doesn't do that on its own.

Comment: i didnt tell them to look at the same database so maybe the server did? i am running windows 7, apache, php 5.3.2, mysql, wordpress 3.0.1 ... what other info needed? btw, creating a new vhost doesn't help actually, now my old wordpress `http://localhost/wordpress` uses the data from my new wordpress `http://jiewmeng` ... also, i noticed that when i goto http://localhost/wordpress now, its using the data from http://jiewmeng and all links goes to http://jiewmeng/...

Comment: somehow it works now ... i dunno whats wrong with it lol ... maybe some browser cache or something ... if anyone happens to have the same issue or know whats wrong let me know

Comment: @jiewmeng strange indeed. :)